# An image view with more possibilities

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, imageview

If you take a look at this app (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=fr.recettetek&hl=en_GB) you'll see it provides image views with a little trash can icon in the top corner which deletes the image. Also the image views have borders around them and show the images without changing their length to width ratio. How is it possible to provide these features or any other feature in image views? Generally how is it possible to customize image views and make them more practical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageView by themselves are used only to display a particular image. To have a custom behaviour or UI, such as the delete icon, you need to make a custom view.

You can do so by extending one of the ViewGroup, such as a RelativeLayout, and make your view.

For details on custom views, please refer to: https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view